# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 13

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, jsonparser

I have a string(var) that I parse as JSON in javascript. But as soon as I do that I get an error stating

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 13

```
var DL_response = {"result":"{"cov_details":[{"issue_date":"UNIT 
 OFFICE,NEYVELI","cov":"MCWG"}],"dl_number":"TN39Y20100000784","address":"PERIYA COLONY  KO PAVAZHANGUDI  
 VIRUDHACHALAM TK","issue_date":"24-03-2020","dob":"21-03-1971","name":"VICNESWARAN 
 S","blood_group":"","validity":{"transport":"","non-transport":"24-03-2010 to 23-03- 
 2030"},"father_husband":"SELVARAJ"}","status-code":"101","request_id":"a9642ae9-2f10-4e9a-9f7e- 
 c3ee1a9a2dbe"}
var Driving_License = JSON.parse(DL_response);
```

What might be causing this error? Is it because of any special characters?

Comment: invalid json.Use online tools like json validato to validate the json

Comment: Because the JSON is invalid, as of position 13, where  a`c` was found that wasn't expected according to the JSON syntax rules. You need to fix whatever is producing the JSON. If it really starts with `{"result":"{"c`, it is indeed invalid, because the fourth `"` (just before the `c`) closes the string that was started two characters prior. It looks like whatever is producing that result is building the string manually, which is an anti-pattern. Instead, build the result structure in memory, and use whatever JSON serialization is built into the platform to serialize the **whole** thing.

Comment: Invalid JSON, as the error says. Your `DL_response` isn't even a string. How would you parse that? Assuming,that just the escapes got lost while posting, you still have plenty of quotes in the wrong place ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your JSON is invalid. And second of all, it's not a JSON string but a JavaScript Object itself. There is no need to parse it again. If the object was valid, you could access it directly without further parsing.

Here is the data I've fixed.

```
var DL_response = {
   "result":{
      "cov_details":[
         {
            "issue_date":"UNIT OFFICE,NEYVELI",
            "cov":"MCWG"
         }
      ],
      "dl_number":"TN39Y20100000784",
      "address":"PERIYA COLONY KO PAVAZHANGUDI  VIRUDHACHALAM TK",
      "issue_date":"24-03-2020",
      "dob":"21-03-1971",
      "name":"VICNESWARANS",
      "blood_group":"",
      "validity":{
         "transport":"",
         "non-transport":"24-03-2010 to 23-03-2030"
      },
      "father_husband":"SELVARAJ",
      "status-code":"101",
      "request_id":"a9642ae9-2f10-4e9a-9f7e-c3ee1a9a2dbe"
   }
}

console.log(DL_response.result.dob)
// output: 21-03-1971
```